# MapReduce, to extract the one row with highest value

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

This is the result(actula output) for reducer. The data is title(key),month and frequency of how many books are borrowed based on the book title(value), and  Is there any way to get the only one row with highest value? For example, I want to choose the only row  with highest frequency among lots of rows. If you know the way, please enlighten me. Thanks a lot.

```
"""E"" is for evidence [sound recording] / by Sue Grafton." 05  8
"""F"" is for fugitive [sound recording] / by Sue Grafton." 05  6
"""G"" is for Grafton : the world of Kinsey Millhone / Natalie Hevener Kaufman and Carol McGinnis Kay." 06  1
"""G"" is for gumshoe [text (large print)] / Sue Grafton."  09,10  1
"""Galapagos"" means ""tortoises"" / written and illustrated by Ruth Heller."   10,04,09  2
"""Git on board 09  1
"""God's banker"" / by Rupert Cornwell."    05,10,11  1
"""Gospodi-- spasi i usmiri Rossi︠i︡u"" : Nikolaĭ II    10,11  1
"""H"" is for homicide [sound recording] / by Sue Grafton." 12  4
```

Comment: Hive, Pig, or Spark has a respective`MAX` function. Are you required to use MapReduce?

Comment: Yea, I am still struggling with this problem, and I have to use MapReduce for education purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run a secondary mapreduce job accepting as input, the output of the first action. The values to write in the Mapper could be (NullWritable, line), as you want to collect all lines to a single reducer, but you don't really care about a key otherwise, then parse out the number of each line, keeping track of the current maximum value and its associated line. After looping over all values, write the maximum line.

To improve the run time of this process, use `setCombinerClass` in your job configuration to use this new reducer